# How do I add custom properties to a Http request using Angular 9

Tags: c#, angular

We have a server side C# method that we use to obtain a user token. At the moment this is primarily called from AWS Lambdas.

This is the method that looks for the token:

```
public static UserIdentity GetIdentityFromRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(UserTokenIdentifierKey))
    {
        return (UserIdentity)request.Properties[UserTokenIdentifierKey];
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("User Token not present on request");
    }
}
```

and then from a C# controller we simply call it using:

```
UserIdentity id = UserTokenAttribute.GetIdentityFromRequest(Request);
```

The issue I have is that in Angular, I cannot find a way of adding the `UserTokenIdentifierKey` to the request properties. Normally, we would add security credentials to the `HttpHeader`, but for some historical reason, it has not been done this way for the C# side.

Can anyone guide me as to how I add this from Angular our typical call for posting uses:

```
public genericPostRequest<T>(uri: string, request: any): Observable<any> {

    const fullUri = this.buildServiceUri(uri);
    const requestAsJson = JSON.stringify(request);
    const requestHeaders = this.getDefaultRequestHeadersObservable();

    return forkJoin(fullUri, requestHeaders)
      .pipe(flatMap((results: [string, HttpHeaders]) => this.httpClient.post(results[0], requestAsJson, { withCredentials: true, headers: results[1] })),
        catchError(this.errorMapperService.handleError));
  }
```

Comment: Does the key need to go in the request body?

Comment: @WillAlexander no, that's the problem. Properties are separate from the request body, but are on the request object. If it was  part of the body, I'd just be able to pass a class and add it as a property of that class.

Comment: Search throughout the C# code for the keyword `UserTokenIdentifierKey` and see where it is added to the request properties, and how (does it originate from a header? a query parameter? the body? etc..)

Comment: It's just that there aren't 100 places on the "request object" that you can place a property. I second Aviad's question: what do you mean by "on the object"?

Comment: From my first sample block you can see that an HttpRequestMessage is being passed in. In the documentation for this, within the Properties section you will see a Properties property. They are getting set on that but from  C# code. It is that property that I'm trying to set using Angular.